# BitLocker issue. Recovery Key is required on each startup after installing secondary OS

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-8-preview, bitlocker

I'm using a laptop with TPM module with BitLocker-encrypted internal HDD, running Windows 7.
Recently I've installed a Windows 8 on the external, eSATA drive.
Windows 8 detected the Windows 7 and correctly replaced the bootloader with dual-boot option.

Unfortunately, I'm now forced to enter BitLocker Recovery Key each time I start the computer.
The only workaround I've found was to disable TPM module in BIOS, and suspend BitLocker on the Windows 7 drive.

How to accomplish the following configuration:

- Keep the BitLocker running on Windows 7 (internal drive)
- Leave the Windows 8 (external, eSATA drive) completely unencrypted
- Don't be bugged to enter Recovery Key each time during startup
- No matter if the eSATA drive is plugged in, or not

Is it possible?
I don't care if TPM is enabled and I just want the Windows 7 drive to be BitLocker-encrypted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to log into Windows 7, suspend Bitlocker (no need to disable your TPM), then reboot your computer into Windows 7 again (and reenable Bitlocker if it doesn't automatically do it). This will "reset" Bitlocker to understand your new dual-boot configuration. Once you've done this, you should not need to enter your recovery key the next time you boot into Windows 7.

Comment: This method also just worked for my upgraded Windows 10 computer.

Comment: I dual-boot Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 18 and this didn't work, still requiring recovery key every time after Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @Youda008, did you ever manage and if so could you add how?

Comment: @Kvothe No :( I gave up and disabled BitLocker.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option, I certainly don't know if it is feasible for you or not would be to unencrypt the the Windows 7 partition, then encrypt again.

I Know, it takes forever and isn't a very attractive option but from what I understand, BitLocker is picky when it comes to user fiddling with disks after the fact.

The other thing I could suggest in hindsight would have been to disable BitLocker encryption temporarily while you installed Windows 8.