# Finding out the reason for BitLocker Recovery popping up

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I've got a message from BitLocker Recovery stating:

> BitLocker needs your recovery key to unlock your drive because your PC's configuration has changed. This may have happened because a disc or USB device was inserted. Removing it and restarting your PC may fix this problem.

This sounds quite straightforward, however I didn't insert any disc or USB device, therefore I'm curious what exactly makes BitLocker to ask for the recovery key. Is there a way to find out (possibly after Windows booted) what was the actual reason for BitLocker Recovery to activate?

Comment: Well, did you change anything else about your computer configuration like exchanging hardware or even fiddling with BIOS settings?

Comment: I didn't change anything intentionally. I may have changed something by accident (in Windows, I think I would remember fiddling with the BIOS or putting in more RAM), but I don't know what, so that's why I'm looking for ways to find out what did I change actually.

Comment: The quote says only what might have happened.  If that isn't a good guess, BitLocker has no idea.  It could have been anything.  Nobody here can know the answer.

Comment: Something triggers BitLocker to ask for the recovery key. BitLocker may guess wrong about that something, but that something is detected somehow. I assume it's logged in Windows somewhere, or Russian hackers can tell me, or it can be read from my horoscope. If that information truly isn't available anywhere in the universe and BitLocker uses `random(10) > 5` to determine if it should ask for my recovery key, I accept that as an answer too, provided that it's properly written. "Nobody here can know the answer" is just an opinion.

Comment: ytg - I'm going to guess that based off of the reasons in the [What causes BitLocker recovery?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383583(v=ws.11).aspx) that it's likely for one of those reasons. Perhaps each specific reason has a correlated Event that you can find from the system event viewer or something. I'm at least trying to give you a starting point perhaps for more research. It's funny MS release MS security updates a couple days ago too though. Wonder if something updated some hardware device firmware causing it to detect a hardware change based on firmware version change?

Comment: Just found this too: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1359375-bitlocker-keeps-asking-for-recovery-key so . . .  Maybe just resolve and move forward and document the date, recent Windows Updates, etc. so the next time—if it happens again to the same machine—you will have some detail to compare, etc. You might look over recent history of Windows Updates and see if you can get a list of device firmware versions from PowerShell or WMIC commands or something. Just tryiong to think of ideas you may find helpful. Document and move on rather than chasing gremlins is best sometimes.

Comment: Frustrating, especially in my case there's 0 unusual activity on the computer (no new hardware, no known software updates, etc) and because of the lack of logging you end up with

---> "Sorry, we're going to repeatedly and abruptly halt your ability to use your computer and NEVER tell you why."

Comment: For those who are beyond finding out why and just want it too stop: https://superuser.com/a/433689/407371

Answer (score 1):

my mobile phone was once charged with Notebook.
now i must connet my phone to usb at power on, otherwise come up the BitLocker Recovery Pop up.

Comment: Welcome to superuser...this is not an answer , it is just your experience of the same type of issue, kindly post such things in the comments and not in answer section

Comment: @Elmo - This is the best answer available until now.