# Why am I prompted for the bitlocker recovery key upon startup?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I recently installed the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. Now, each time I start my computer,  I'm prompted for the bitlocker recovery key. In response to each prompt,  I  enter the key hoping this will be the last time. But it isn't.

I've not noticed any other problems.  Once I'm logged in everything seems to run fine.  I have easy access to the key but it's a hassle to enter it every single time. I'm also not ready to rollback the update either... close but not there yet.

The computer is a two year-old Dell XPS 9550 with a single 500gb SSD running Windows 10 installed at the factory. It is regularly updated with  Windows patches and less frequently applied hardware patches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? https://superuser.com/a/433689/23133

Comment: this happens when any major change has happened to Windows or the hardware. Before upgrades you need to suspend bitlocker.  @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 link should fix the issue

Comment: Yea, the linked answer should solve your problem. If the problem continues, you'll need to check the status of the TPM in your BIOS.

Comment: If you suspect anything is not correct about your TPM configure, be sure you have a working recovery key, before you change any setting otherwise if you mistakenly wipe the TPM you will be unable to access your data.