# BitLocker asks for recovery key after every boot (dual-boot system)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, bitlocker, tpm

I dualboot Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu. I recently reinstalled W10 and installed a Trusted Platform Module, which directly enabled me to encrypt C: (and D:) and automatically decrypt on boot.

However, I lost my grub upon the Windows reinstall. No issue there as I could just force booting into linux from the bios, run update-grub and it was back. However, now I am asked for the recovery key every time I boot into Windows.

**How can I stop the recovery key from being needed?**

Things I've tried:

- decrypting and re-encrypting C:
- wipe the TPM via the troubleshooter (windows reboots without recovery key, but next reboot it asks again)
- delete and add the protector (as suggested [here](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-9570-BitLocker-asks-for-recovery-key-after-dual-boot/td-p/6240947)):

> 1. `manage-bde -protectors -get C:` to find the TPM ID
> 2. `manage-bde -protectors -delete C: -ID {XXXXX}`
> 3. `manage-bde -protectors -add C: -TPM`

General info:

```
C:\Windows\system32>manage-bde -status C:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Disk volumes that can be protected with
BitLocker Drive Encryption:
Volume C: []
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 445,54 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100,0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:
        TPM
        Numerical Password
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BitLocker issue. Recovery Key is required on each startup after installing secondary OS](https://superuser.com/questions/433048/bitlocker-issue-recovery-key-is-required-on-each-startup-after-installing-secon)

Comment: Ah, I did the disable-reenable trick, but without rebooting in between. Will try that right now! (I see suspending could've been enough, but that's too late now)

Comment: It's a pain but you could disable and enable BitLocker.  The recovery key is requested when a configuration change is detected.

Comment: In the end, I arrived to the same conclusion as [Mike Kasberg on his blog](https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html): "Although Windows is listed in grub, booting Windows from grub with BitLocker enabled won’t work because the system’s TPM will detect a change in the boot sequence. To avoid this problem, you should boot Windows directly from your computer’s BIOS boot menu - usually accessible by pressing F12 on startup."